# MySQL error in upload: 1 errors were found during analysis

Tags: php, mysql

I need your help. I tried to upload a MySQL file
and I got this error:

```
1 errors were found during analysis.

6 values were expected, but found 7. (near "(" at position 191)
SQL query:

-- 
-- Дамп данных таблицы `bb` 
-- 
INSERT INTO `bb` (`id`, `time`, `ip`, `user`, `pass`, `guard`, `checked`) 
VALUES (1, '2018-02-27 17:33:18', '31.172.204.119', 'zazacaca32', 'caca', 'dcd'), 
       (71, '2018-02-28 14:43:37', '95.24.40.161', '@zazacaca32', 'vk.com/zazacaca32', '47QMX', 0)

MySQL said: Documentation

#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Could you please help?

Comment: What kind of "analysis" is that? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error message already says it clearly...

First values block contains only 6 of 7 elements.

edit:

```
(1, '2018-02-27 17:33:18', '31.172.204.119', 'zazacaca32', 'caca', 'dcd')
```

count the values...

Comment: how do i fix it

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bb` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` text NOT NULL,
  `user` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `pass` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `guard` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `checked` int(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=72 ;

Comment: INSERT INTO `bb` (`id`, `time`, `ip`, `user`, `pass`, `guard`, `checked`) VALUES
(1, '2018-02-27 17:33:18', '31.172.204.119', 'zazacaca32', 'caca', 'dcd'),
(71, '2018-02-28 14:43:37', '95.24.40.161', '@zazacaca32', 'vk.com/zazacaca32', '47QMX', 0);

Comment: where is the problem here or in another place

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed one value of the checked field. It should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO `bb` (`id`, `time`, `ip`, `user`, `pass`, `guard`, `checked`) 
VALUES 
(1, '2018-02-27 17:33:18', '31.172.204.119', 'zazacaca32', 'caca', 'dcd', 0), 
(71, '2018-02-28 14:43:37', '95.24.40.161', '@zazacaca32', 'vk.com/zazacaca32', '47QMX', 0)
```